# Assigning max value of column grouped by another column dynamically in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I would like to assign max values of a dynamically named column grouped on another static column. I think the best way to represent my problem is through an example.

Suppose I have the following dataframe, `my.events`:

```
           x        title typethx typesea
1 2016-11-24 Thanksgiving       1       0
2 2016-11-25 Thanksgiving       2       0
3 2016-11-26 Thanksgiving       3       0
4 2016-11-26       Season       0       1
5 2016-11-27       Season       0       2
```

There's an overlap of dates between the two event types on `2016-11-26`. Therefore, I want to group by my `x` column and then mutate the `type` columns to their max values.

In a static implementation, this would be written as:

```
my.events <- my.events %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(typethx = max(typethx),
         typesea = max(typesea)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The result would look like:

```
           x        title typethx typesea
1 2016-11-24 Thanksgiving       1       0
2 2016-11-25 Thanksgiving       2       0
3 2016-11-26 Thanksgiving       3       1
4 2016-11-26       Season       3       1
5 2016-11-27       Season       0       2
```

However, I would like to dynamically mutate my `type` columns. I'm first attempting to dynamically alter one `type` column. In this case, let's say I want to apply my mutate on `typethx`, so I create a variable `name = "typethx"`. Now, I've tried the SE method using `mutate_` and also the `lazyeval` method. None of them were successful, resulting in errors or wrong outputs (see below for my attempts).

**Attempt A:**

```
new.events <- my.events %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(!!name := max(!!name)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Result A:**

```
           x        title typethx typesea
      <fctr>       <fctr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 2016-11-24 Thanksgiving typethx       0
2 2016-11-25 Thanksgiving typethx       0
3 2016-11-26 Thanksgiving typethx       1
4 2016-11-26       Season typethx       1
5 2016-11-27       Season typethx       2
```

**Attempt B:**

```
new.events <- my.events %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate_(lazyeval::interp(~name = max(name), name = as.name(name))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Result B:**

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "new.events <- my.events %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate_(lazyeval::interp(~name ="
```

**Attempt C:**

```
new.events <- my.events %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate_(lazyeval::interp(~name, name = as.name) = lazyeval::interp(~max(name), name = as.name(name))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Result C:**

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "new.events <- my.events %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate_(lazyeval::interp(~name, name = as.name) ="
```

**Attempt D:**

```
new.events <- my.events %>%
  group_by(x) %>% mutate_(name = lazyeval::interp(~max(name), name = as.name(name))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Result D:**

```
           x        title typethx typesea  name
      <fctr>       <fctr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 2016-11-24 Thanksgiving       1       0     1
2 2016-11-25 Thanksgiving       2       0     2
3 2016-11-26 Thanksgiving       3       1     3
4 2016-11-26       Season       3       1     3
5 2016-11-27       Season       0       2     0
```

**Bonus points:**

I was thinking of looping through my `type` columns and doing the mutates, but if there's a way mutate all of them at once, then that would be great. Just for prior knowledge, these `type` columns were dummy variable columns that I had created in a prior step. For the sake of preserving the scope of the problem, you can safely assume that there's a variable called `dummy.cols = c('typethx', 'typesea')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to apply on multiple columns use `mutate_at`

```
my.events %>% 
     group_by(x) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(starts_with("type")), max)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   x [4]
#   x          title        typethx typesea
#   <date>     <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 2016-11-24 Thanksgiving       1       0
#2 2016-11-25 Thanksgiving       2       0
#3 2016-11-26 Thanksgiving       3       1
#4 2016-11-26 Season             3       1
#5 2016-11-27 Season             0       2
```

Comment: Omg, thank you! I didn't know about the `mutate_at` method (R noob here). Learned something new!

Comment: Since my dummy columns may not always start with `type`, I used the below implementation, where my `dummy.cols` variable is an array of dummy column names. `new.events <- my.events %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate_at(dummy.cols, max) %>% ungroup()`. Thanks again for your splendid answer!

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr  yes, you can pass a character vector or other convenient functions in `select` based on the patterns